# Bing Maps V8 - Uncaught ReferenceError: amd is not defined

Tags: javascript, maps, bing, bing-maps

Yesterday api was working. Today an error occurs:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: amd is not defined**

Can someone help me please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>loadMapAsyncHTML</title>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='printoutPanel'></div>

    <div id='myMap' style='width: 100vw; height: 100vh;'></div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
            var map;
            function loadMapScenario() {
                map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
                    credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key'
                });
            }


    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?branch=release&callback=loadMapScenario' async defer></script>
</body>
```

**UPDATE**

This error was fixed by Bing Team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/31063241-34a2-4787-82ba-8e58bf1a2800/uncaught-referenceerror-amd-is-not-defined?forum=bingmaps

found a fix, add:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.amd = function(){};
        window.amd.define = function(){};
    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='//www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?branch=release'></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The team is investigating the root cause as it appears something has changed in the hosting platform which is causing this issue. No code was changed in any of the Bing Maps branches. In the mean time, many have implemented the workaround that David referenced.

**Update**: A hotfix is being rolled out. You should start seeing Bing MAps V8 loading again as as the hotfix rolls our across our data centers/servers.

If you license Bing Maps (i.e. are a paying customer), make sure you have logged an incident with the Bing Maps Enterprise support team. This will allow them to send you an incident report in the next week or so with details on this incident. If you do not have contact details for the support team, you can find them here:  https://www.microsoft.com/maps/support.aspx

Comment: my team uses the bing v8 api and we also noticed that this service is down. We're subscribed to `https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/ rss` but there's `no information indicating this issue`. Is there a different status page we should point to? Without these `system critical notifications` my team is not able to mitigate these situations. We are paying for this service and we feel that these notifications should go out to ourselves and other dev shops `using` for your product.

Comment: I agree, this caught my web app off guard and it's odd to see StackOverflow as my news source for outages.

Comment: Bing Maps isn't an Azure service, so no notifications are posted on the Azure site. All Bing Maps customers have access to the Bing Maps Enterprise support team. If you see any issue, contact them and they will investigate. For outages like this they will provide regular updates. You can find contacts and details for support here: https://www.microsoft.com/maps/support.aspx

Comment: When an issue like this happens (first time in years that I can remember) we try and keep people updated everywhere we see them report the issue, whether it be on StackOverflow, the MSDN forums, twitter, emails, or directly through the support team.

Comment: It look like your last tweet was sept 7, so I'm not seeing the outage updates you just mentioned. I don't want to go on a rant, I'd just like to see issues like this reported on all relevant channels. Little things like this determine if my team continues it use of product or moves to another product like Google maps. I like api but feel the notification process is a little lacking for a power house like Microsoft.

Comment: The tweet was to individuals who reported the issue on twitter.

Comment: It's frustrating. Other services I use, like AWS, *proactively* alert users when an issue is confirmed even if they aren't using them. Using support for outages sets a scary precedent. It lets me know in the future, any issue I have relatively close to Bing Maps, I should go to support and make sure things are up. We use `AMD` too, and wasted hours thinking it was us. An RSS feed is a simple request -- and would have let me known going into my stakeholder meeting that there was an outage before my team lost credibility.

Comment: I'll pass this feedback to the leadership team.